# laravel use closure with relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Assume I have a `Group` and `Student` model, it's a one-to-many relationship;

`Group` has many `Student`,every `Student` has `id` and `tuition` attribute.

So I want get Group with students numbers and all the tuition .

Here is my code:

```
Group::with(['student'=>function($query){
        $query->select(DB::raw('count(`id`) as numbers, sum(tuition) as total')); 
    }])->paginate(10);
```

It's not working,I tried print the sql, and the sql:

```
select count(id) as numbers, sum(tuition) as total from `group` where `student`.`group_id` in (`1`, `2`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `11`, `12`, `13`, `14`)
```

I can get results when run raw sql in mysql, but laravel doesn't return anything about `count` or `sum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `withCount()` instead of `with()`:

```php
Group::withCount([
    'student as numbers',
    'student as total' => function($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw('sum(tuition)'));
    }
])->paginate(10);
```

Solution for Laravel 5.2:

```php
Group::selectRaw('(select count(*) from students where groups.id = students.group_id) as numbers')
    ->selectRaw('(select sum(tuition) from students where groups.id = students.group_id) as total')
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: I'm using laravel 5.2, it says call to undefined function.Any idea?

Comment: `withCount()` requires Laravel 5.3. I added an alternative with raw subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `withCount()` instead of `with()`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Answer (score 0):

Tested a lot;

When I use `find` get only one row.

```
Group::with(['student'=>function($query){
    $query->select(DB::raw(' group_id ,count(`id`) as number, sum(tuition) as total')); 
}])->find(1);
```

It worked.

The only thing I miss is I need  select `student.group_id`,which means `foreign key` in `hasMany` relationship.

But when you want use `paginate` or `get` method fetch multiply rows.

You will only get a total result in your first model object with others are null.

```
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name":"first",
            "student": [
                {

                    "group_id": 1,
                    "number": 129,
                    "total": "38700.00"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name":"second",
            "student": []
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name":"third",
            "student": []
        },
```

Just add `->groupBy('group_id)` and you will get what you want

```
 Group::with(['student'=>function($query){
    $query->select(DB::raw('id, class_id ,count(`id`) as numbers, sum(tuition) as total'))->groupBy('group_id'); 
}])->paginate(10);
```

Result:

```
 {
            "id": 1,
            "name":"first",
            "student": [
                {

                    "group_id": 1,
                    "number": 40,
                    "total": "12000.00"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name":"second",
            "student": [
                {

                    "group_id": 2,
                    "number": 43,
                    "total": "12900.00"
                }

                       ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name":"third",
            "student": [
               {

                    "group_id": 3,
                    "number": 46,
                    "total": "13800.00"
                }
             ]
        },
```